# Match ${variable} occurrences in a text using regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I am currently working in an application where I need to find all occurrences of strings like ${[0-9-a-zA-Z]} in a bigger string. Here is my method:

```
def countVariables(str) {
    def pattern = ~'${sss}'
    def matcher = str =~ pattern
    print matcher.count
}
```

Now the problem.

When I pass a string like "asidb ${sss} asodniasndin", I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: sss for class: ConsoleScript83
```

I think that, given that in Groovy ${} are properties, I'm having these conflicts. 
In this case, I would have to run the whole text searching for the dollar sign and replacing it for something else? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using single quotes so groovy doesn't do the expansion and just gives you a string?

Ie:

```
countVariables( 'asidb ${sss} asodniasndin' )
```

Comment: Also I would rewrite the regex pattern like this:
`def pattern = ~/\$\{sss\}/`
This escapes the symbols $, { and }.

Comment: Thanks @Riggs! I was just going to say it pointed an error in my regex. Thanks tim!